# What is the difference in meaning between the sentences"You can be a singer or a dancer" and "You can either be a singer or a dancer"?

Tags: meaning, pronouns, semantics, sentence-meaning

Do the sentences  have the same meaning ?If they have same meaning,the use of the word"either" seems somewhat redundant in this particular type of sentences as the meaning still remains intact after removing it.But if the meanings of these sentences are different, then the case could be different however.Can somebody explain this?

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a nuance of difference.

"You can be a singer or a dancer."

doesn't seem to specifically exclude the possibility of being both.

"You can either be a singer or a dancer."

does, in my opinion, exclude that possibility.